# Server Architecture

Tags: installation, debian

I've been given a completely wiped server that I plan on installing Debian on.

I need to make sure that I download the right version of Debain for the CPU architecture. The motherboard is a `Thunder n4250qe (s4985-e)` manufactured by TYAN.

Would I be correct in thinking this is an AMD64 motherboard. I have Googled it and the link to the manufacturers page is here http://www.tyan.com/support_download_cpu2.aspx?socketid=16.

I just want to make 100% sure in case I download and burn an incorrect version of Debian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, all AMD [Opterons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opteron) are 64 bit processors.

Answer (score -1):

[Debian amd64 7.1 ISO-DVD:](http://cdimage.debian.org/debian-cd/7.1.0/amd64/iso-dvd/)

debian-7.1.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso;debian-7.1.0-amd64-DVD-2.iso;
debian-7.1.0-amd64-DVD-3.iso;

debian-update-7.1.0-amd64-DVD-1.iso

At the link below, cheerful man who can not embed the driver in the distributions of Windows installed on this motherboard Debian. But first, he set a W2K3)))

[Thunder n4250QE & Super Micro CSE-0059 - Page 2](http://www.overclock.net/t/665241/thunder-n4250qe-super-micro-cse-0059/10)

"completely wiped server"?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the images – are those in any way related to the question?

Comment: @slhck I just want to know that it is in this case completely wiped server. Pictures match my imagination on this subject). Thank you!